# Polymer and shared styles. Using fonts like font-awesome all over a project

Tags: css, fonts, polymer, font-awesome

How can I use [font-awesome](http://fontawesome.io/) all over my project? I would ideally like to include it once in the head tag or similar like any other project. But because of the ShadowDOM of the webcomponents, it is not recognized.

I know there is a [shared styles](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#style-modules) solution in polymer but won't this add all of font-awesome into every single little component and take up memory and performance?

I have also seen there are polymer components for font-awesome like [this one](https://customelements.io/vangware/fontawesome-iconset/), but I would rather not use it this way. This requires the use of iron-icon and also I already have a project I am trying to port so I'm using font-awesome the standard way `<i class="fa fa-cog"></i>`. And it requires yet another dependency to make font-awesome work which could stop support at any time since it is not maintained by the font-awesome team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name says shared styles are shared and not loaded for every component. They are loaded once and applied where they are included.

Comment: Okey, sounds great but do you have any doc or other ref that it works like this? Would be great if it does but I didn't find it in the docs https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#style-modules

Comment: I remember discussions about it but I have no memory of where this was. Everything else would be hillarious anyway. The browser also doesn't load resources from the same URL twice but uses the previously loaded ones.

Comment: Yea that's true. It would definitely make sense working that way. If you find any references to this feel free to update the answer. I'll mark it as answered in the meantime.